# wget : connection reset by peer in redhat linux

Tags: connection, wget, reset, peer

I am trying to access remote `soa`p URL through `wget` command in `RedHat linux` but some times i get below `Exception`. What could be the reason for below Error. I am expecting `HTTP 200` response but instead getting below error.

```
lgadmin@mnpgategui1 apps]$ wget --no-check-certificate https://remote ip:port/mnpserver/services/mnpservice?wsdl
--23:54:42--  https://remote ip:port/mnpserver/services/mnpservice?wsdl
Connecting to remote ip:port... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify IP's certificate, issued by `/C=IN/ST=NCR/L=XXX/O=YYY Technologies/OU=TEL/CN=SSS':
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
WARNING: certificate common name `SSS' doesn't match requested host name `IP'.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.
```

Regards,
Jay

Answer (score 1):

It is usually when a firewall drop the connection or the host is a proxy to another host, and the other host drop

Comment: Thank you. This occur only during night window between 22:00 PM till 23:59 PM in which we send/receive more than 2 lakh + soap message with remote URL.

Comment: In that case i would check and investigate any firewall that sits between the two hosts, maybe some QoS or flood protection

Comment: Yes the firewall exist between two hosts.. I will discuss with our network team. Thank you for info.